# Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x10aa1b600) to 'NSString' (0x10b4dab48)

Tags: ios, json, swift

My json has googleplus links of restaurants and it shows null if restaurant does not have any googleplus link But I get error of as mentioned above.

```
if dict["googlepluslink"] != nil
{
    self.googlepluslink.append((dict["googlepluslink"] as? String)!)
}
else
{
    self.googlepluslink.append(("-" as? String)!)
}
```

> Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x10aa1b600) to 'NSString' (0x10b4dab48)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use `if let` or `guard` statement to check `dict["googlepluslink"]` is String or not and then according to that you can append your data like below

```
if let link = dict["googlepluslink"] as? String 
{ 
    self.googlepluslink.append(link)
} 
else {
    self.googlepluslink.append("-")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    self.googlepluslink.append((dict["googlepluslink"] as? String)!)
```

This is totally weird and self contradictory.

You take something out of a dictionary. The result is an optional value, plus it could be an object of about any class, for example NSNull.

You then cast it to String using as? which means you get an optional string, and no crash if the dictionary contained nothing or something that couldn't be converted to String!

Then you use the ! operator which *will* crash if your optional String is nil. That doesn't make any sense it all.